# else if condition is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I use Registration form as pop up window.So I validate the form using jquery. At that else if condition is not working.I don't know whats a problem????

Script-Coding:

```
$(document).on('click', "#btnregister", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var name = $("#name").val();
            var formemail = $("#email").val();
            var formreemail = $("#confirmemail").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var confirmemail = $("#confirmemail").val();
            var emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$";

            if ($("#name").val() == "") {
                    $("#name").focus();
                    $("#errorBox").html("Please fill YourName...");
            } else if ($("#email").val() == "") {
                    $("#email").focus();
                    $("#errorBox").html("Please fill YourEmail...");

            } else if ($(name != '' && email != '' && confirmemail != '')) {
                $("#errorBox").html("...ThankYou for Your Registration!..")
            }
            var url = $(this).attr('data-url');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: $('#formRegister').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#widgetContainer1').html(data);
                    $('#widgetModal1').modal('show');
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#widgetContainer1');

                }


            });

        });
```

Comment: Not working as in? What is the issue. Be Specific.

Comment: what have you tried so far, please mention that ? Also paste your HTML here to check on our side

Comment: What do you mean by `else if condition is not working` as there are so many else condition, which one is not working?

Comment: Why don't you paste your HTML?

Comment: You do not stop submitting if any fail. You need to MOVE the bracket `}
        var url ` to AFTER the ajax

Comment: Ask yourself, is `$(name != '' && email != '' && confirmemail != '')` meaningful?

Comment: In script if condition is true or false it display  the error msg as "Please fill your Name". Remaining else if conditions are not working. I use alert msg inside the else if whether the condition is work or not.But alert is not display.So, I conclude that else if condition is not working.

Comment: $(name != '' && email != '' && confirmemail != '')                                          How could you say its not meaningful??

Comment: It is fine - perhaps a little unnecessary since you already tested they were not blank

Answer (score 0):

1. your regex is wrong - it needs / / and not quotes as in 
   `var emailRegex = /[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/;`
2. you need to not ajax if there are errors and not thank them until success
3. I would grab the submit event instead of the button click

```js
$(function() {
  $("#regform").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $("#name").val();
    var formemail = $("#email").val();
    var formreemail = $("#confirmemail").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var confirmemail = $("#confirmemail").val();
    var emailRegex = /[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/;
    if ($("#name").val() == "") {
      $("#name").focus();
      $("#errorBox").html("Please fill your name...<br/>");
    } else if ($("#email").val() == "") {
      $("#email").focus();
      $("#errorBox").html("Please fill your email...<br/>");
    } else if (!emailRegex.test(formemail)) {
      $("#email").focus();
      $("#errorBox").html("Please fill a valid email...<br/>");
    } else if ($('#confirmemail').val() == "") {
      $("#confirmemail").focus();
      $("#errorBox").html("Please confirm your email...<br/>");
    } else if (!emailRegex.test(formreemail)) {
      $("#confirmemail").focus();
      $("#errorBox").html("Please fill the valid email in confirm field... ");
    } else if (confirmemail != email) {
      $("#confirmemail").focus();
      $("#errorBox").html("Emails are not matching, Please re-enter again...<br/>");
    } else if ($(name != '' && email != '' && confirmemail != '')) {
      var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $('#formRegister').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
          $('#widgetContainer1').html(data);
          $('#widgetModal1').modal('show');
          $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#widgetContainer1');
          $("#errorBox").html("...Thank you for your registration!..<br/>")
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="regform">
  Name:
  <input id="name" value="" />
  <br/>Email:
  <input id="email" value="" />
  <br/>Confirm:
  <input id="confirmemail" value="" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" />
  <div id="errorBox"></div>
```